# In Python3 scripting how to use shebang line with virtualenvwrapper in multiple environments

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, shebang

I have a fully functional framework of python scripts that can import and interact. 
My problem is that the shebang line must point to my virtualenv:

```
#!/Users/me/.virtualenvs/kube3/bin/python
```

when the code gets committed to git my specific personal directory path is committed and shared with other environments that have a kube3 virtualenv in a different location peculiar to their environment e.g.

```
#!/Users/someone_else/.virtualenvs/kube3/bin/python
```

How do I avoid having a peculiar path and still use virtualenvwrapper?

after trying

```
#!~/.virtualenvs/kube3/bin/python

#!$WORKON_HOME/kube3/bin/python
```

I thought of these possible solutions: 
 1. direct virtualenv to a root path i.e /.virtualenvs/
 2. To create a symlink in all target environments and point the shebang line to the symlink

is there another better way?

Comment: Which operating systems? On linuxy platforms, `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is usually the right choice. `/usr/bin/env` finds the python on your path and the virtualenv setups up the right path for its python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/642070/tdelaney my station is mac but it needs to run on a linux probably ubuntu or centos

Answer (score 3):

Use: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Unix-like systems read the top of files to see how to execute them. If the first two bytes are `#!` it treats the first line as a program that should be run after appending the current file as the final argument. The famous shebang.

Surprisingly (at least to me), the executor doesn't look on the `$PATH` for the program - it must be a relative or absolute file system path. Traditionally, distros link `/bin/sh` to whatever your shell program is, so `#!/bin/sh` works.

Just by luck, distros usually put `env` in `/usr/bin`. `env` lets you set environment variables to run a program in an alternate environment and it  looks on the `$PATH`. We are kinda gaming the system. `#!/usr/bin/env python3` doesn't set additional variables, but it gets around the shebang path rule.

When a virtualenv is activated, it modifies `PATH` so that its python is first on the list, so `env` finds the python you want.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand your suggestion works when the virtual environment is activated or the base python is installed. I'm up-voting your answer please add this proviso